# Adding extra parameter to git commit

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

We have a custom-made system to track client tasks/projects. We manually add a checklist and mark them off, often also adding the time it took for each point. This is very useful but a bit redundant, as we also provide the same information in git. So I'm thinking of somehow adding an extra parameter to git that allows me to indicate how long something took, and then extract this data and save it in a database (we normally use PHP/MySQL). How would one go about this?

I think of doing:

`git commit -m "Adding search functionality" 15`

And then somehow being able to extract the 15 (minutes) to process it later on, together with the description of this task, so that we do not have to add "Adding search functionality" which took 15 minutes separately. I'm thinking of a hook that takes this second parameter and uses it as a variable to be passed on to a PHP script. Is this feasible?

Comment: You could also use some type of marked up item in the Git comment itself. Something like "My checkin comment TIME-DEV=15min". Then on each commit parse the checkin message and do the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can integrate your custom arguments into the commit message itself and then parse this later

```
git commit -m "foo [15min]"
```

or maybe

```
git commit -m "bar [00:00:15]"
```

Now its quite easy to find `[]` and parse the values within.

Github, redmine, bitbucket (and so on) does something similar, when they link commits to issues and vice versa

```
git commit -m "Fixed bug [Closes #42]"
```

You should think about using a real bug/issue tracker instead of "a checklist" anyway.

Comment: Interesting! But how do you parse them later? How to access these arguments?? [sorry, very new to git]

Comment: +1. Better to embed the command inside the git comment itself. Then your integration just has to parse the output of `git log --oneline` and follow the commands you've embedded.

Comment: +1 for suggesting real bug tracking, one of two nigh-essential items needed for software development (the other being SCM).

Comment: Thanks, `git log --oneline` sounds perfect for exporting this info!

Comment: I'd be wary of doing this in the commit subject. It's nice for those to be short, so it's annoying to take up space for boilerplate, especially if it might expand later. The parsing would be a lot more robust if you required it to be on its own line in the body, too, e.g. `fixed the frobotz\n\nit was fribbitzing\nbugid: 45\n...` (sorry about the embedded newlines)

Comment: @Jefromi: I don't see any instability, when one puts it into the subject with unique delimiters (`[...]`). You can also include a keyword like `[Time YY:MM:DD]`. The downside of your approach is, that you must retrieve the whole commit messages, instead of just the first line, for parsing the metadata, but at the end it's just another solution, of course.

Comment: Right, there's no instability as long as this is all the metadata you ever want in your commit subjects, and as long as no one ever tries to put a bracket in for another reason.

Comment: @Jefromi: Hooks are flexible enough that you can do sanity checks against the data within your delimiters. In fact, all it would take is a regex and some simple "if match then extract else leave it be" logic to make the parsing forgiving -- or extend it for other types of metadata tags. Saying "no one can ever use brackets in their commit subject" is a bit dramatic.

Comment: @justin: Okay, seriously, enough nitpicking. We all understand that embedding tags in the commit subject is (1) less extensible/flexible and (2) easier to hack up parsing code using one-line summaries. Obviously it's a horrible solution if you have ten fields you want to attach to every commit, and it's completely fine if you'll only ever have one short one. Draw the line where you like.

Comment: @Jefromi: The moment, when you need ten fields of metadata appended at your commit (that is not covered by the commit itself already, like the committer, or the author), then it seems, that you did something wrong. However, I agree that in that situation the less important metadata can go into the log-summary. -- "Saying "no one can ever use brackets in their commit subject" is a bit dramatic." Thats the reason, why I mentioned keywords ;) Sayin "No one can ever use `[TIME=` in the subject is less restrictive

Answer (score 2):

Usually such things are added to the commit messages itself and then extracted ( hooks, scripts, bugtrackers etc.)

You can also look at using `git notes` ( you can even add them without rewriting existing commits) , but the only problem is in sharing them, which is not very straightforward.

http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html